# XYZ tiles in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, xyz-tiles

When I 1st started with QGIS 3.4.4 I added google maps/ satellite/ relief and they worked for 2 days but now I can't see any form of mapping through the XYZ tiles.
I have reinstalled, I have deleted and redone the XYZ tiles, I have uninstalled all of my plugins and I have used EVERY single URL on  these links:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py
And yes, switched my computer off and on again!

The latest set of instructions i am following is:
https://www.xyht.com/spatial-itgis/using-openstreetmap-basemaps-qgis-3-0/

And not a single XYZ tile loads, I have NO background mapping!

Have I somehow blocked the XYZ tiles from loading on QGIS?

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with QGIS 3.4.4?

Comment: Try the QuickMapServices plugin. It provides easy access to many of the same XYZ tile basemaps you're using. If that doesn't work, my next suggestion is to look into whether something has changed with your internet connection. Are you on a work or school computer? Talk to the IT department and find out if they changed some settings that might block XYZ tiles.

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark, but a nasty little source of error: you need to remove the `$` before each matrix parameter, i.e.

```
https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

Note: I also omitted the domain prefix to let QGIS/the OSM server automatically choose from the available.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simple plugin called [Tile+](https://www.geodose.com/2018/11/qgis3-basemap-plugin-tile-plus.html). This Plugin provides some popular basemap like OSM, Bing, ESRI, Google, Stamen and also some updated earth data like rainfall rate, earth visibility, sea surface temperature, etc.